# Image paths in Compass CSS on Windows

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

I've been using SASS and Compass successfully on my Windows 7 x64 machine. Everything was working fine until I tried using the [replace-text-with-images](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/utilities/text/replacement/#mixin-replace-text-with-dimensions) mixin.

I placed the image I'm trying to use in the correct place (`t:\Website\stylesheets\stylesheets\images` for my system), and checked that relative assets are enabled in my Compass config file. Still, when I try to compile, I get this:

```
t:\Website\stylesheets>compass watch -c config_with_refresh.rb
>>> Change detected to: code-n-apps.scss
WARNING: 'i_user.gif' was not found (or cannot be read) in t:/Website/stylesheets/images
Errno::ENOENT on line ["34"] of C: No such file or directory - t:/Website/stylesheets/images/i_user.gif
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
>>> Compass is polling for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
```

The file is most definitely in that path, and is readable.

Any help would be most appreciated. Ideally, I'd like Compass to grab the images directly off my production server (http), but even having it work locally would be a major improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You say that this is your image-path:

> t:\Website\stylesheets\stylesheets\images

Then of course it will not find i_user.gif in

> t:/Website/stylesheets/images/

Please double check your path, note that the first time you are using `stylesheets/stylesheets` and you want to load the image from `stylesheets`